# belongs_to not using primary key option

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I've been struggling with this for a while, and decided to throw it out there:

I have 3 models, User, Connection, Suspect

A User has many Connections, 
A Connection has one Suspect, linked via case_id

A User has many Suspects through its Connections.

The code is as follows:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :followers
  has_many :suspects, :through => :followers
end

class Connection < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :suspect, :primary_key => :case_id , :foreign_key => :case_id
end

class Suspect < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :connection, :primary_key => :case_id , :foreign_key => :case_id
end
```

The problem is that the belongs_to seems to ignore the :primary key.

If I do

```
u = User.find(:first)
u.suspects
```

The SQL generated is:

```
SELECT `suspects`.* FROM `suspects` INNER JOIN `connections` ON `suspects`.id = `connections`.case_id WHERE ((`followers`.user_id = 1))
```

However it should be:

```
SELECT `suspects`.* FROM `suspects` INNER JOIN `connections` ON `suspects`.case_id = `connections`.case_id WHERE ((`followers`.user_id = 1))
```

Can someone point me in the right direction?

James

Comment: Is :followers supposed to be :connections?  Is there a reason that a Suspect does not have many connections?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The docs for belongs_to say that you can use the :primary_key option, but we have never been able to get it to work either. That said the latest version of rails, 2.3.3, specifically has a [fix for this](http://github.com/rails/rails/commit/b3ec7b2d03a52e43a4451d522eea7e6499289daa)

Comment: Has it been fixed yet in 3.0? I'm getting the same problem.

Comment: this has been fixed in 3.x, but please note that rails console reload method doesn't reflect this change, i had to quit console and start it again. @mohawkjohn

Answer (score 1):

After more testing, @pallan is correct, this was fixed in 2.3.3 but only for the first level of association, not for has_many :through.

For example:

```
Connection.suspects
```

Uses the correct SQL, but

```
User.connections.suspects
```

Does not.

I'm going to open a ticket for it now.

JP